# How to convert .net collection type to VBA collection?

Tags: c#, .net, vba, collections

I am writing a VBA application which calls to C#.net method which returns collection object.

When I assign the output to VBA.Collection I get a compile time error - Argument not optional.

If I assign the output to Object I get run time error - Object variable or With block variable not set

I think it is because of incompatible Collection type.

Can anyone help me to convert .net collection type to vba.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that's doing this? It'd be easier to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to use the SET command?